# How to create own annotation for junit that will skip test if concrete exception was thrown during execution?

Tags: java, junit4

My application have several execution modes, and in 1 mode it is normal that some of my tests will throw a concrete exception. I need to annotate this methods with something like @SkipOnFail that will set method as skipped if exception was thrown.

thanks in advance!

@Edit(for my question to be more clear)

```
@Test(expected=ConcreteException.class)
```

does not work for me because i need my tests to pass even if ConcreteException.class was not thrown(expected tag in junit will mark my test as failed if this exception won't be thrown), and to be skipped otherwise. In all other cases it should work as always.

@Solution that worked for me(junit v4.7) thx to @axtavt

```
@Rule
public MethodRule skipRule = new MethodRule() {
    public Statement apply(final Statement base, FrameworkMethod method, Object target) {
        if(method.getAnnotation(SkipOnFail.class) == null) return base;

        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                try{
                    base.evaluate();
                } catch (ConcreteException e) {
                    Assume.assumeTrue(false);
                }
            }
        };
    }
};
```

@Thx

Comment: Why don't you use the `@Expected` jUnit annotation ?

Comment: I can't set expected annotation property for @Test method because according to junit javadoc if method doesn't throw an exception or if it throws a different exception than the one declared, the test fails. but i need my method to succeed if no exception was thrown and to be skipped if a concrete exception was thrown.

Comment: What you mean the test is skipped? Is is somehow ignored or simply silently passed?

Comment: Why don't you use a try catch block with the concrete exception?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that such a feature is available out of the box, but it should be pretty easy to implement with [custom `TestRule`](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Rule.html) and [`Assume`](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assume.html), something like this:

```
@Rule
public TestRule skipRule = new TestRule() {
    public Statement apply(final Statement base, Description desc) {
         if (desc.getAnnotation(SkipOnFail.class) == null) return base;

         return new Statement() {
             public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                 try {
                     base.evaluate();
                 } catch (MyExceptoion ex) {
                     Assume.assumeTrue(false);
                 }
             }
         };
    }
};
```

Comment: Why don't you just `catch MyException` instead of any `Throwable`?

Answer (score 2):

What about using [JUnit Extensions](http://junitext.sourceforge.net/index.html)?

The following example is taken from their [Tutorial](http://junitext.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html).

It provides aditional annotations for Prerequisites (@Prerequisite): Ignore tests based on conditions.

The required approach would be to check this during running tests. So you can simply add a `@Prerequisite(requires="")` annotation.

```
public class TestFillDatabase {
    @Prerequisite(requires = "databaseIsAvailable")
    @Test public void fillData() {
        // ...
    }

    public boolean databaseIsAvailable() {
        boolean isAvailable = ...;
        return isAvailable;
    }
}
public class TestFillDatabase {
    @Prerequisite(requires = "databaseIsAvailable")
    @Test public void fillData() {
        // ...
    }
    public boolean databaseIsAvailable() {
        boolean isAvailable = ...;
        return isAvailable ;
    }
}
```

This specified methods with `@Prerequisite(requires = "databaseIsAvailable")` must be a public method, returning a boolean or Boolean value.

If these methods will be consolidated in helper classes, you can also specify static methods within a class to be called using `@Prerequisite(requires = "databaseIsAvailable", callee="DBHelper")`.

```
public class TestFillDatabase {
    @Prerequisite(requires = "databaseIsAvailable", callee="DBHelper")
    @Test public void fillData() {
        // ...
    }
}
public class DBHelper {
    public static boolean databaseIsAvailable() {
        boolean isAvailable = ...;
        return isAvailable ;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I need my test to pass if exception was not thrown, not to fail. But it should be skipped if one concrete exception was thrown.

Comment: Today I ran into a toolkit called JUnitExt so I have updated my answer to demonstrate what I believe could be a candidate solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Also using the Assume class (since jUnit 4.4), you can use [assumeNoException()](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Assume.html#assumeNoException(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable)):

```
try{
    base.evaluate();
} catch (ConcreteException e) {
    Assume.assumeNoException("Concrete exception: skipping test", e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for the docs about JUnit and it appears that from version 4.9 they have introduced what they call test rules (see [TestRule](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html)). You may start from this.

The [ExpectedException](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) class marked as `@Rule` could be of some help in order to check for exceptions thrown but not mandatory for the test to pass.

For more advanced usage I cannot say for the moment as I've just discovered it.