# Skip TestNG test on concrete exception thrown during execution

Tags: java, integration-testing, testng

**This is related to the question [How to create own annotation for junit that will skip test if concrete exception was thrown during execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804039/how-to-create-own-annotation-for-junit-that-will-skip-test-if-concrete-exception), but for TestNG.**

I seek a solution to configure TestNG integration tests to be skipped (and not fail) on known list of infrastructure exceptions which can appear every now and then.

After surfing through the TestNG code I understood that I can't achieve that using `IHookable` or other listeners. Also TestNG doesn't have anything similar to JUnit's `@Rule TestRule` objects. Also, making all infrastructure exceptions to extend the TestNG's `SkipException` is not an option for me.

Did I miss something?

Comment: TestNG doesn't have `@Rule` because it doesn't need it...

Comment: How do I satisfy my need without `@Rule` with TestNG then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [IInvokedMethodListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html) and in the afterInvocation method do something like

```
public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {

if(testResult.getThrowable().getClass().equals(YourExceptionClass.class))
     testResult.setStatus(TestResult.SKIP);
}
```

Set this listener in your testng.xml or based on however you are executing your tests.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work indeed. Somehow failed to notice this in the sources.